# Как скрыть кнопку при проверке полей на заполнение?

Tags: html, css

Имеется форма обратной связи, хотел сделать чтобы при заполнении всех полей формы появлялась кнопка. Сделал с помощью CSS но не работает. Кнопка находится всегда на веду и активна. Подскажите что не так?

```css
.form__input {display:block;width:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:8px;background-position:right 0.75rem center;outline:0;border:1px solid #e5e5e5;-webkit-transition:border-color 0.15s linear;transition:border-color 0.15s linear;}
.form__input[required] {background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxNicgaGVpZ2h0PScxNicgdmlld0JveD0nMCA4IDE2IDE2JyBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0nbmV3IDAgOCAxNiAxNic+PHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9J3RleHQvY3NzJz4uc3Qwe2ZpbGw6I0YxODI2MDt9PC9zdHlsZT48cGF0aCBjbGFzcz0nc3QwJyBkPSdNNy4yIDE3LjRsLTUuNCAzLjgtMS40LTIuNSA2LTIuNy02LjEtMi44IDEuNC0yLjQgNS40IDMuOC0uNS02LjZoMi43bC0uNSA2LjYgNS40LTMuOCAxLjQgMi40LTYgMi44IDYuMSAyLjgtMS40IDIuNS01LjQtMy44LjUgNi41aC0yLjhsLjYtNi42eicvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input[required]:focus:invalid {border-color:#cf5340;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij48Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9IiNDRjUzNDAiIGN4PSI4IiBjeT0iOCIgcj0iOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input[required]:valid {border-color:#b4d388;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij48Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9IiNCNEQzODgiIGN4PSI4IiBjeT0iOCIgcj0iOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input:invalid ~ .form__sub {display:none;}
```

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" id="table1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
 <tr>
 <td><input class="form__input" id="name" type="text" name="f2" size="30" style="width:100%;" maxlength="70" placeholder="Ваше имя" required></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input class="form__input" id="tel" type="text" name="f4" size="30" style="width:100%;" maxlength="70" placeholder="8 (___) ___-__-__" required> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input class="form__input" type="text" name="f1" size="30" style="width:100%;" placeholder="E-mail" required/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><textarea rows="3" name="f3" cols="30" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Опишите что вам нужно сделать..." required></textarea>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center"><input class="form__sub" type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто убери бесполезную таблицу. И вообще, табличная вёрстка устарела давным-давно.

```css
.form__input { box-sizing: border-box; }
.form__input + .form__input, .form__sub { margin-top: 4px; }

.form__input {display:block;width:100%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:8px;background-position:right 0.75rem center;outline:0;border:1px solid #e5e5e5;-webkit-transition:border-color 0.15s linear;transition:border-color 0.15s linear;}
.form__input[required] {background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0naHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmcnIHdpZHRoPScxNicgaGVpZ2h0PScxNicgdmlld0JveD0nMCA4IDE2IDE2JyBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0nbmV3IDAgOCAxNiAxNic+PHN0eWxlIHR5cGU9J3RleHQvY3NzJz4uc3Qwe2ZpbGw6I0YxODI2MDt9PC9zdHlsZT48cGF0aCBjbGFzcz0nc3QwJyBkPSdNNy4yIDE3LjRsLTUuNCAzLjgtMS40LTIuNSA2LTIuNy02LjEtMi44IDEuNC0yLjQgNS40IDMuOC0uNS02LjZoMi43bC0uNSA2LjYgNS40LTMuOCAxLjQgMi40LTYgMi44IDYuMSAyLjgtMS40IDIuNS01LjQtMy44LjUgNi41aC0yLjhsLjYtNi42eicvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input[required]:focus:invalid {border-color:#cf5340;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij48Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9IiNDRjUzNDAiIGN4PSI4IiBjeT0iOCIgcj0iOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input[required]:valid {border-color:#b4d388;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNiIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNiIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDE2IDE2Ij48Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9IiNCNEQzODgiIGN4PSI4IiBjeT0iOCIgcj0iOCIvPjwvc3ZnPg==");}
.form__input:invalid ~ .form__sub {display:none;}
```

```html
<input class="form__input" id="name" type="text" name="f2" size="30" style="width:100%;" maxlength="70" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input class="form__input" id="tel" type="text" name="f4" size="30" style="width:100%;" maxlength="70" placeholder="8 (___) ___-__-__" required>
<input class="form__input" type="text" name="f1" size="30" style="width:100%;" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
<textarea class="form__input" rows="3" name="f3" cols="30" style="width:100%;" placeholder="Опишите что вам нужно сделать..." required></textarea>
<input class="form__sub" type="submit" value="Отправить сообщение">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь буду именно так писать ))

Comment: @Алексей, если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: С удовольствием, но на какую именно галочку я не могу понять? Я даже еще не разобрался как тут ставить "+ репу" тому кто помог

Comment: @Алексей, вот принятие ответа https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0VKL.png (можно принять только один ответ, если принимаешь другой, с первого галочка снимается). Кнопки голосования тоже рядом - стрелки вверх и вниз.

Comment: да спасибо большое. Все понял

Answer (score 2):

Всё дело в том, что css не позволяет "гулять по дереву назад", Вы лишь можете по условию изменить вложенные элементы или следующих в этом же родителе. Вам нужно навесить какой-то класс на элемент `form`, ну, либо, если он у Вас единственный на странице - можно и грубо (но лучше не стоит) вот так:

```
form:invalid .form__sub {
    display: none;
}
```

Это вместо `.form__input:invalid ~ .form__sub {display:none;}`

Comment: Так у меня именно форма на таблице стоит и нет form ... Тут работает же данная функция http://andrew-r.ru/notes/?go=all/css-validation/

Comment: все сделал .... спасибо!!! Привязал к table class="form"

Comment: А как сделать так с помощью css чтобы вместо, когда нет кнопки был текст информации что нужно заполнить все поля ... И как только поля будут заполнены и появится кнопка, текст скроется?

Скриншот http://savepic.net/10155653.jpg

Comment: @Алексей, ну так же и сделайте, только наоборот - `.form:valid .kakoi-to-text { display: none; }`

Comment: от души )))) Заработало ))